# Need info regarding iOS Development Certificate

Tags: ios, code-signing-certificate

Apart from Apple's Developer Portal, are there any tools available by which one may create an iOS *Development* Certificate?

Are there any tools apart from Keychain Access by which I can examine the contents of a .cer file?

Does a given .cer file contain any information regarding the original certificate signing request? Or regarding the computer/system from which the Certificate was created?

This is ***NOT*** a request for endorsement. I want to know how somebody may have created a certificate in my account without my knowledge.

Comment: What is it that you think happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's `.cer` files are [X.509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) certificates.

`openssl x509 -text -noout -inform der -in ~/your_file.cer` will allow you to read your file contents but I do not believe if will include the sort of information you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the fastlane action, [cert](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/cert/README.md), can create certificates. It still needs your credentials. I do not know the answers to your other questions.